# How to Build Online Installer for my Application using VS 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer

I have built an application having some prerequisites. Now we have a requirements to built an installer which will be an online installer i.e the installer will download all the required or the installer from my cloud server and then install the applications and check all prerequisites and if not present will install them.

As far as I know, the normal MSI Installer will not solve this purpose.

Can anybody please help me with the same?

Comment: Most commercial products like InstallAware support that, so you should use a search engine instead.

Comment: Hi Lex, I know commercial product can do the Job for me but I was looking for a non -commerical option.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a more advanced installer than whatever comes out of the box.

Here's a link that might be helpful.
https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-web-installation.html

There's another tool called WiX that provides more control over the creation of installers.
https://wixtoolset.org/

Comment: Indeed, using a Wix bundle would be a very good option. But this is opinion-based.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using Wix. Can you please provide me some sample code of using Wix for installation of a normal desktop or console Application as that would help me to proceed much more effectively. I am going though their documentation but finding it diffcult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Possible steps to build online installer
1. Build and create your Nuget package and Npm package
2. Update all production configuration for service
3. Build automatic version checking in the installer, if there was new version available , then the installer will notify to download 
4. follow application installer build package

In real project, we will use DevOps tool to deploy package. I recommend use Teamcity and Octopus to deploy package.